# Is there a way to restart pm2 process using cron but only if it's not already running?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to restart my Node.Js app using PM2 through

`pm2 restart app.js`

using crontab but ONLY if the app is not already running (e.g. if my server crashed and restarted and pm2 didn't restart).

the command above restarts it anyway even if it's running.

How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I do not want my app to restart if it's already running. I want it to restart *only* if it's listed as "stopped" or if it is not running.
Some suggestions offer to write a bash script, but what would it be? I tried the options below, but they either don't work or restart the app even if it's running.

Comment: what is purpose of doing this?

Comment: you should prevent to restart pm2 if it's not running, but on which condition it will restart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better way of doing it is use the `pm2 startup` command

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

To get the automatically-configured startup script for your machine you need to type this command:

```
# Detect available init system, generate configuration and enable startup system
pm2 startup
```

You can specify the platform you use by yourself if you want to (where platform can be either one of the cited above):

```
pm2 startup [ubuntu | ubuntu14 | ubuntu12 | centos | centos6 | arch | oracle | amazon | macos | darwin | freebsd | systemd | systemv | upstart | launchd | rcd | openrc]
```

The output of this command can be a recommendation of the line to copy/paste with all environment variables and options configured for you.

Example:

> [PM2] You have to run this command as root. Execute the following command:
>         sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/home/unitech/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3/bin pm2 startup  -u  --hp

You simply have to copy/paste the line PM2 gives you and the startup script will be configured for your OS.

Once you run the `sudo pm2 startup`. It will create the `systemctl service`. You can check the status of the same using

```
systemctl status pm2-root
```

By default the service is not configure to restart automatically. You will run the below commands

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/pm2-root.service.d
```

and then create a file name `10_auto_restart_pm2.conf` with below content

```
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

After that execute

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart pm2-service
```

Now let's test the auto restart part

```
$ systemctl status pm2-root.service
● pm2-root.service - PM2 process manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-root.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/pm2-root.service.d
           └─10_auto_restart_pm2.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-02-28 16:52:19 UTC; 11s ago
     Docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
  Process: 5014 ExecStop=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5022 ExecStart=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5031 (PM2 v2.10.1: Go)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 24.3M
      CPU: 460ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/pm2-root.service
           └─5031 PM2 v2.10.1: God Daemon (/home/vagrant/.pm2)
```

Now we kill the process manually and wait for 3 seconds

```
$ kill -9 5031
$ sleep 3
$ systemctl status pm2-root.service
● pm2-root.service - PM2 process manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-root.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/pm2-root.service.d
           └─10_auto_restart_pm2.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-02-28 16:52:55 UTC; 641ms ago
     Docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
  Process: 5057 ExecStop=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5081 ExecStart=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5088 (PM2 v2.10.1: Go)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 24.3M
      CPU: 461ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/pm2-root.service
           └─5088 PM2 v2.10.1: God Daemon (/home/vagrant/.pm2)
```

As you can see the process/service was restarted automatically. No cron needed and it is how you should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but at which point do I specify which app is getting restarted?

Comment: You will run the app using pm2 and then setup the startup script.

Comment: would need to use cron if the user doesn't have sudo level permissions

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking to do is start any stopped apps without incurring downtime. A good solution is to use the `pm2 startOrReload` command. This will start any stopped apps, and will reload any current apps without incurring downtime.

You'll need a config file for the command. if you don't currently have one you can create it using `pm2 ecosystem`. Make sure it points to `app.js`.

Then run this command in your cron job:

```
pm2 startOrReload <your ecosystem file>
```

See `pm2 -h`, `pm2 startOrReload -h`, and `pm2 ecosystem -h` for more options.

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't want to restart the current process if it's already running? If I restart my app it logs out the users and may cause bugs.

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin this doesn't restart your app, it reloads it. Users won't be logged out and you will not experience downtime. [As opposed to restart, which kills and restarts the process, reload achieves a 0-second-downtime reload](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of launching the pm2 process within the cron, launch a bashscript which checks if the pm2 is already running and restarts it if it's not the case.

**Edit**

Try following (it might be that the pgrep expression needs to be adjusted, I don't know the exact name of the pm2 process):

```
#!/bin/bash

pID=$(pgrep -x "pm2") 

if [ -n "${pID}" ];
then
    #do nothing 
    echo $pID "already running. not restarting." 
else
    # start it 
    echo "restarting"
    # put your command to start your process here
fi
```

Comment: What would this bashcript look like? The one in the link you provided restarts the app even if it's running. And when the app is stopped, it doesn't restart it.

Answer (score 2):

## For Linux

My use case: Run the app every 3 seconds.

**Easy way:**

`pm2 startup` This creates a command, copy and run it.

`pm2 start app.js --restart-delay=3000` Each 3000 ms restart the app

`pm2 save`

Finally, reboot Linux and test.

## For Windows

Use case: Run the app.py at every 3rd minute.

1. https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer
2. `pm2 start app.py --cron "*/3 * * * *" --no-autorestart --time`
3. `pm2 save`

Restart Windows and check.

## More Info

- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/
- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Aydin K. answer

```
#! /bin/bash -l

ps cax | grep PM2 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $(date -u) - "PM2 is running."
else
  echo $(date -u) - "Restarting PM2."
  cd ~/app-location
  ~/bin/node ~/bin/pm2 start app.js
fi
```

#### Explanation

Breaking each code.

`-l` in `#! /bin/bash -l` will use your environment variables from `.bashrc`

`ps cax | grep PM2 > /dev/null` gets the number of processes with PM2 (Case-capital) since the process is named as "PM2 ..."

`~/bin/node ~/bin/pm2 start app.js` this is a big catch. You need to use `node` before using `pm2` commands in cron. Also you need to use the location where your `node` and `pm2` are installed. Can be found by running `which node` on your shell.

The cron can be configured to run every 15 minutes (or as per your preference)

```bash
*/15 * * * * ~/amb-cron.sh >> ~/logs/pm2-process.txt`
#you can create a log for your echos.
```